# Is the data traffic between Lightsail and S3 free?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-lightsail

I've researched it for about an hour but I could not get a clear answer for this.

Does the data traffic between S3 buckets and AWS LightSail instances incur any cost, assuming they are in the same region / belong to the same user account?

Answer (score 1):

From the [faq](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/):

> How do I use IPs in Lightsail?: Each Lightsail instance automatically gets a private IP address and a public IP address. You can use the **private IP** to transmit data between Lightsail instances and **AWS resources privately, for free**.

> What types of data transfer do I get charged for?: When you exceed the monthly free data transfer allowance of your instance plan, you **will get charged** for data transfer OUT from a Lightsail instance to the Internet or to another AWS Region or to **AWS resources in the same Region** when using **public IP addresses**.

Thus, one can conclude that if your S3 traffic goes over internet using your public IP address, the traffic will not be free. To ensure free transfer you  **must** ensure that it goes through **private IP**.

p.s.

Sadly I don't know how to ensure the use of private IP in Lightsail for S3 traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your research. I don't think it answers the original question yet. I've looked into S3 VPC endpoint and it looked like it's rather a special routing than a private IP addressing. I guess I'll wait for the bill and if it becomes a problem, I would bridge the S3 traffic to an EC2 instance in my own VPC. Overengineering, yay.